# Android Studio org.xml.sax.SAXParseException , how to remove it

Tags: android, gradle

Error:FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task `:lib:processDebugResources`.

  ```
  java.io.IOException:` org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; 
  columnNumber: 33; The prefix `android1` for attribute 
  "android1:versionCode" associated with an element type "manifest" 
   is  not bound.
  ```
- Try:

## Run with --`stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output.

2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task `:app:processDebugManifest`.

  ```
  com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: 
  org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 33; The 
  prefix "android1" for attribute "android1:versionCode" associated 
  with an element type "manifest" is not bound.
  ```
- Try:

  ## Run with -- `stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s

Comment: from what I've read `Saxon` won't run on `Android` -- it's not a JVM.  But, I don't have a source for you.